# The group of units of the cyclic ring of order $p^b$ is cyclic

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, cyclic-groups

Let $U(C_{p^b})$ be the group of units of the ring $C_{p^b}$ where $C_{p^b}$ is cyclic of order $p^b$.

Show that $U(C_{p^b})$ is cyclic.

Comment: Any thoughts? ${}$

Comment: With $C_{p^b}$, do you mean the ring $(\Bbb Z_{p^b}, +,\cdot)$ of integers modulo $p^b$?

Comment: No, it is any cyclic group of order $p^b$. I have struck on it in On Finite Groups Having Perfect Order Subsets by Ashish Kumar Das, page 634.

Comment: But you referred to the *ring* $C_{p^b}$. Note also that the unit group of the integers mod $2^k$ is not cyclic for $k \ge 4$.

Comment: @Derek: It is also not cyclic for $k = 3$.

Comment: $p$ is a Fermart prime number.

Comment: @tohn: Right.  Please state that *in your question*, so that you are asking for a proof of a true statement.

Comment: http://dspace.nehu.ac.in/bitstream/1/2552/1/dasIJA13-16-2009%5B1%5D.pdf. Page 634

Comment: @tohn: What I mean is that you should go back and **edit your question**, not include this extra information in the comments.  At present, anyone who reads your question will see that it is (i) completely unmotivated and (ii) false as stated.  You have addressed both of these points in the comments, but you're still wasting everyone's time by not correcting them in the question itself.

Answer (score 4):

It helps a lot to know that you are reading [this paper](http://www.m-hikari.com/ija/ija-password-2009/ija-password13-16-2009/dasIJA13-16-2009.pdf).  (I suggest that you edit that into the question.)

Note that in the paper $p$ is a Fermat prime, hence of the form $2^{2^k}+1$: in particular it is odd, which is relevant to the structure of $U(C_{p^b})$.

For any cyclic group $(C_n,+)$, the automorphisms are given by multiplication by an integer relatively prime to $n$: we get the group $U(n)$ of order Euler's function $\varphi(n)$. Note that if we choose a generator of $C_n$ we get an isomorphism to $(\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z},+)$ and then the group automorphisms correspond to the elements of the unit group of the ring.  So it doesn't really matter whether we think of $(C_n,+)$ as a ring or not; either way we get to the unit group $U(n)$.  (But $U(n)$ does not act by ring automorphisms -- these must fix $1$.  It's just the action of any unit group of a ring by multiplication on the elements of the ring, which gives automorphisms of the additive group of the ring.)

The structure of $U(n)$ is classical number theory, first determined by Gauss.  In particular it is cyclic if and only if $n$ is:
$\bullet$ $1$, $2$ or $4$; or
$\bullet$ An odd prime power $p^b$, or twice an odd prime power $2p^b$.

For a proof see e.g. $\S$ 1.6 of [these notes](http://alpha.math.uga.edu/%7Epete/4400FULL.pdf).  This answers your question: you have a Fermat -- hence odd -- prime power, so the unit group is cyclic.